# Very simple Regex false positive on 4 digit (\d{4}) search

Tags: php, regex

I am missing something here.

I am trying to see if a string contains 4 digits. I have done this before but not for years and cannot work out what I am doing wrong.

$stuff is a string from a mySQL db. (Currently coming from a form so should certainly work.)

```
$stuff=$_POST['stuff'];
$regex="/\d{4}/";
$integerStuff=intval($stuff);//in case somehow seeing as  n on-digit!!!
if (preg_match($regex, $integerStuff)) {echo "  Found 4 dig";}
```

I thought if preg_match did NOT find the pattern it returned false but while 123 does not match, 12345 etc do.

I thought the {4} meant EXACTLY 4 occurrences.

Dumb question I know but have been stuck on this for ages.

Comment: `{4}` means exactly 4, but your regex is not anchored and matches anywhere in the string. The `int` cast may also return zero, if there is leading garbage before the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said,

`$regex="/\d{4}/";`

looks for exactly 4 digits. But whats before or after doesnt matter. You want to include the "line-start" ^ and "line-end" $:

`$regex="/^\d{4}$/";`

Comment: @tkausi you are a life saver thanks. Wasted well over an hour on this. I may be back if I get stuck again :-)